# How is frequency related to data rate?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, modulation, bandwidth, frequency-modulation

How does (if it does) frequency affect/relates to Data Rate.

Why for example using the same modulation, LoRa (in the physical layer),
you get somewhere around 250kbps at 2.4Ghz and only 20kbps at 868Hz ?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.se Christos K. ! Where did you get those numbers? To my knowledge, LoRa exclusively operates in the sub-Ghz ISM band (see, for example, ,https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2017/6/23/lorawan-data-rates/).

Also, note that LoRa is not a modulation scheme. The modulation scheme used by Lora is Chirp-Spread-Spectrum (CSS).

Comment: also, there's simply no inherent relation between carrier frequency and data rate. This becomes obvious when you think about the complex baseband representation being the same, regardless of the carrier frequency, and that carrying identical information to the passband signal.

Comment: More context is needed.

Answer (score 3):

There's simply no inherent relation between carrier frequency and data rate.

I assume a classical comms engineering education here, but since that most often introduces the concept of *equivalent baseband* early, a good explanation would be:

> This becomes obvious when you think about the complex baseband representation of a passband being the same, regardless of the passband's center frequency, and that the complex baseband carries identical information to the passband signal.
>
> Thus, carrier frequency cannot have direct influence on the information transport capabilities of any system, given that you mix the same signal to these carriers.

Indirectly, there might be influences: Bandwidth is proportional to capacity; it's impossible to get 1 GHz bandwidth centered around 433 MHz, but cheap around 60 GHz.

Noise and interference are the other limit to capacity; these are different for different bands and technologies.

Comment: Using an upper side band modulation you could get 1 GHz bandwith at a carrier frequency of 500 MHz or even at 10 kHz... Am I missing something ? (other than 10 kHz not suitable for RF, or existing broadcast standards)

Comment: Hm, I tried to avoid this confusion by illustrating it as  "1 GHz *centered* around 433 GHz".

Comment: yes yes I saw that... I was actually referring to my own statement...

Comment: ah, OK; but then, while your carrier would be 10 kHz, your *central* freq would still half the bandwidth plus 10 kHz, if you will.

Comment: hmm that sounds ok...

Comment: @Fat32 How can you have 1 GHz bandwidth at carrier frequency of 10 KHz?

Comment: @BlackMath It sounds weird doesn't it? You know about Single Side Band modulation that only transmits the upper half of the two sided spectrum. So first separate the positive and negative frequencies of the baseband 1 GHz message, then upmix (by 10 kHz!) the positive sideband and by -10 kHz the negative sideband, giving you a 1 GHz bandwidth at 10 kHz carrier... Is there anything you would like to add, if this was contradicting some forgotten or hidden theory ?

Comment: @Fat32 But at a central frequency of 10 KHz, you can have 10 KHz maximum at each side, a total of 20 KHz, right?

Comment: @BlackMath that's *Double Side Band*, but I was referring to *Single Side Band* anyway, this really is an impractical gedankenexperiment type of thing...